# How do I get rid of the blank line when I use UNIQUE in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter

[image]

I used `unique`... the result is in column B, but I want results to look like column  C. So what do I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>""))
```

[image: 0]