# Struggling to filter out the blank cells?

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a spreadsheet that has two sheets. I want a unique list to be generated on my 'programming sheet' in the equipment category list, from the 'single exercise list' sheet. However, I want it to ignore blank cells. I tried using the formula:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER('single exercise list (working)'!E4:E,'single exercise list (working)'!E4:E <>"")'single exercise list (working)'!E4:E)`

Where I am filtering out if e4:e is not equal to zero, but this is returning an error. Is it because of the drop-down list in 'single exercise list' sheet?

I have attached the sheet, D8 is my problem in the programming sheet.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13cMd4klKySVRudYPQZc1AAnGrm1MKZXEXpk_Zdee5XE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get rid of the blank line when I use UNIQUE in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/127362/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-blank-line-when-i-use-unique-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is incorrect, you have an extra range in there.

Try using
`=UNIQUE(FILTER('single exercise list (working)'!E4:E,'single exercise list (working)'!E4:E <>""))`.
The `UNIQUE()` formula will automatically reference the result of the `FILTER()`, no need to add that extra range at the end.

Hope this helps, please let me know if you have any questions, or if this does not work for you.